# Spark finding duplicates using spark temp view vs direct dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Question is on using the best way to find the duplicates from one data frame,

**Option 1:** Converting to Temp View and using SQL statement

```
Df.createOrReplaceTempView("TEMP")

spark.sql("select count(1),keycolumn from TEMP group by keycolumn having count(1)>1").count()
```

**option 2:** Directly using aggrigate function in spark

```
df.groupBy("keycol").agg(count("keycol")).alias("new_col").filter("New_col">1).count()
```

Which option works effectively and why?

Comment: Are using Azure databricks?

Comment: In terms spark execution plan both will generate same plan. By the way in the 2nd option, you want to check count > 1 instead of keyCol > 1.

Comment: @HimadriPal , Thank you. yes count > 1 ( yeh i missed it)

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula Cloudera hadoop

Comment: You can compare the two solutions by assigning the output of the two queries to a variable, let’s name it output, and run output.explain(). You’ll get the execution plan.